# Add custom classes to angular chosen container

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-chosen

CODE : http://plnkr.co/edit/H2hmEukfjaPL1T4W298O?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="chosen@*" data-semver="1.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.0/chosen.min.css" />
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.20"></script>
    <script src="chosen.jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="chosen.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <select chosen class="red" ng-model="bar">
      <option>Hi</option>
      <option>This is fun</option>
      <option>I like Chosen so much</option>
      <option>I also like bunny rabbits</option>
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['localytics.directives']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

You can see that I tried to add class `red` to the `div` created by angular-chosen, together with other classes `chosen-container chosen-container-single`. I don't want to change those classes manually.

What is the right way to make sure additional classes got added?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like line 153 of `chosen.jquery.js` has an option for `inherit_select_classes` that defaults to `false`.

line 39 of the directive in `chosen.js` looks at the `chosen` attribute for the `options`:

```
options = scope.$eval(attr.chosen) || {};
```

so making your select markup:

```
<select chosen="{inherit_select_classes:true}" class="red" ng-model="bar">
```

results in this being generated:

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single red ng-pristine ng-valid localytics-chosen" >
```

(omitted extra attributes not relevant to this question)